# How to specify "no files except these extensions" in rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync

I've created an rsync --include-from file by using a find command to find directory names of interest, and format them as such `+ dirname/***`, which copies it and its contents. This works as intended, but to cut down on total transfer size I need to further specify some file types I want to include, and exclude all others.

The problem I'm having is finding a rule that excludes all files but not directories (there are directories with `.` in their name which makes it more difficult). It looks as though `- ! */` is exactly what I want (from the [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)), as it should exclude anything that isn't a directory (meaning all files?) but it seems to never match anything.

Currently my format for the includes file is as follows:

> + desired file extensions `+ *.txt`
>
> - all other files (the problem, trying `- ! */`)
>
> + all desired directories and their contents `+ cooldir/***`
>
> `- *`

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Try exclude all: `--exclude="*"`, followed by including the file types you want: `--include="*.sh"`.

Comment: @roaima yep thank you, including all directories and pruning the empty ones helped out a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include and exclude options apply from left to right: for any given file or directory the first one that matches is the one that's applied.

In your case you need to declare the exclusions before the inclusions. Here's an example using explicit `--include` and --exclude`options rather than the more generic`--filter` option you're using

```
-avHXP                         # My standard set of options
--include 'essentials/***'     # Include absolutely everything in here
--exclude '*.tmp'              # Exclude *.tmp files from everywhere else
--exclude '*.sh'               # Exclude *.sh files from everywhere else
--include 'interesting/***'    # Include this directory tree (not *.tmp or *.sh)
--include 'exciting/***'       # Include this directory tree too (not *.tmp or *.sh)
--prune-empty-dirs             # Don't create directories that would end up being empty
```

The general approach for excluding all files but including directories is this. Once you start including files you'll almost definitely want the `--prune-empty-dirs` option too

```
--include '**/'
--exclude '*'
```